# How can I pass "type" attribute within <html:text> in struts1

Tags: jsp-tags, struts-1

When I try to write something like this: `<html:text styleId="Istituto" type="number">` in the struts1 it gives me an error

> Attribute type invalid for tag text according to TLD

How can I add "type" attribute to `<html:text>` tag?

Comment: You can't. html:text is a tag used to produce an `<input type="text">`.

Comment: But <html:number> doesn't exist. In such case how it possible to make input of type number using jstl?

Comment: You can generate the input by yourself, or create a tag equivalent to html:text, or realize that Struts 1 is an officially abandoned project for years, and start using something modern and maintained.

Comment: The canonical answer is to modify the taglib's TLD to accept dynamic attributes. IIRC Struts 1.3 already does this, but I might be wrong about that.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old, but I'm currently working on a super old application that uses Struts 1 framework, and today I had the same problem. Here's the solution I'm using that works:

```
<input type="number" name="budgetValue" 
 value="<bean:write name="applicantForm" property="budgetValue"/>">
```

Where:
budgetValue - is the Form property; applicantForm - is the Form

Comment: Worked as expected for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `Milebza` for the answer, but for me only this way has worked.

```
<input type="number" name="budgetValue" value="${applicantForm.budgetValue}" />
```